# MySQL update join with limit

Tags: mysql, sql, join, phpmyadmin

I would like to know how to update a table, with values from another table, by the trick is I need to set a limit because I have thousands of rows to update, and PHPmyadmin can't handle that load. ( I dont have direct access to the server )

My table structure looks like this

**wp_postmeta**

`meta_id,
post_id,
meta_key,
meta_value`

**wp_map**

`oldmap, newmap`

What I need to do is join the two tables on `wp_postmeta.meta_value` and `wp_map.oldmap`, and update the `wp_postmeta.meta_value` with `wp_map.newmap`.

Here is my current query, but I need to add a `LIMIT` of 100 to the query, as I'm splitting the query up into smaller chunks so PHPMyAdmin can process.

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta
INNER JOIN wp_map
ON wp_map.oldmap = wp_postmeta.meta_value
SET wp_postmeta.meta_value = wp_map.newmap;
```

I read about creating a subquery, but couldn't find any relevant examples, so if someone could steer me in the right direction or provide a working example it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've never used phpMyAdmin, but I don't see why it would care how many rows you're updating. The work is done by the server, not phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't use a `LIMIT` clause in a multi-table `UPDATE` query.

Comment: perhaps you need to setup a bigger transaction timeout in phpAdmin

Comment: @cha This is WPEngine hosting, so that is not possible

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try it this way

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta t JOIN
(
    SELECT p.meta_id, m.newmap
      FROM wp_postmeta p JOIN wp_map m
        ON p.meta_value = m.oldmap
     ORDER BY p.meta_id
     LIMIT 100
) s
   ON t.meta_id = s.meta_id
  SET t.meta_value = s.newmap;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/47c4e4/1)** demo

Comment: +1 for using the meta_id. and not having to change the Limit after each run, it's nice!

Comment: @TinTran Is there any way to speed this up? I have 700,000 rows in postmeta, and I ran that query with LIMIT 1, and it took 30 minutes on my local machine

Comment: Just as a note, this will scan the entirety of the wp_postmeta table, so it won't perform well.

Answer (score 1):

It's rather unconventional , but it should help you in a pinch

```
SET @tmp_c = 0;
UPDATE
    table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
INNER JOIN table3 ON table2.id = table3.id
SET
    table1.remove_date = NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MONTH
WHERE
    table1.active = 1
AND
    (IF (table1.active = 1, @tmp_c := @tmp_c + 1 , 0 )) //This is to only increment the counter if the whole where matches
AND
    @tmp_c <= 15 //Start ignoring row items as soon as it exceeds the limit amount
```

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6f04b1/1/0)</kbd>
in this example I am only doing 5 rows, you can change the limit to `0,100` if you'd like

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta,
      (SELECT oldmap,newmap
       FROM wp_map 
       ORDER BY oldmap,newmap limit 0,5)as wp_map
SET wp_postmeta.meta_value = wp_map.newmap
WHERE wp_map.oldmap = wp_postmeta.meta_value
```